# kendoui: set calendar depth for column in kendoGrid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have date column in my grid, with format `dd/MM/yyyy` when I set field like `12/12/12` it updates grid with `11/12/12`, (that happens due to silly time conversion:
`kendo.parseDate('Mon Dec 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)').toISOString()`. Is there any way to fix this?)

So I decided to stick with just 'Month Year'.
This is in grids columns array:

```
{ field: "published", title: "Published", format: "{0:MMMM yyyy}",
```

Dates are correct as Month Year on rows, but `datepicker` in edit mode pops up with 'day' precision, how do i tune it?

Comment: Are you sure about that the conversion is "silly"? What I see is that 00:00:00 in CET is actually 23:00:00 in GMT (timezone used in ISO). So, in GMT timezone is still one day before (11 Dec 2012). So the question is if you are not worried about GMT time but local time, why do you use `toISOString()`.

Comment: Actually I don't quite care about time of day, just need day which I set there, guess that's gonna annoy user...

Comment: Now it's even worse, it moves it one month back, event if it's middle of the month

Comment: Did you keep in mind that months are base 0 (January = 0)?

Comment: You don't care about time but the problem is that `Date` in JavaScript and in Kendo-UI include time so you cannot ignore it. So you should keep it in mind. Recommendation: Work always on same timezone and do not change between local and ISO. Always ISO or always local.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I slapped it hard with the wrapper:

```
function Date2MDY(date) {
  var dmy = '';
  dmy += String(date.getMonth()+1) + '-'
  dmy += String(date.getDate()) + '-'
  dmy += String(date.getFullYear())
  return dmy;
}
```

And it fixed the issue